# Get friend's Email ID from twitter account through Android application

Tags: android, twitter

Can I get my friend's email id from twitter account through android application?

I am trying to use twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar for my app to connect and post to twitter and it is working fine.

But I cannot find user information and user friend's list and also their Email ID.

Comment: @RS26 Please don't format words that aren't code with code formatting.

Comment: I don't think so Twitter gives email id of friends (mutual follow)

Answer (score 0):

> If you'd like a user's email address, you'll need to ask a user for it
>   within the confines of your own application and service. The Twitter
>   API does not provide the user's email address as part of the OAuth
>   token negotiation process nor does it offer other means to obtain it.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6718